# Need to remove lines till a pattern is matched

Tags: regular-expression

My C code needs to decode some application data that were received over a socket by another application. I used the Wireshark to export the packets(many) into a C array. But the array carries all bytes comprising IP address/Port. I just need the application data.

The C array is:

```
static const unsigned char pkt64[393] = {
0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x06, 0xd8, 0x9d, /* ........ */
0x67, 0x16, 0x55, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, /* g.U..... */
0x45, 0x00, 0x01, 0x79, 0xf1, 0x09, 0x40, 0x00, /* E..y..@. */
0x40, 0x06, 0xc1, 0xee, 0x0a, 0x17, 0x6f, 0x35, /* @.....o5 */
0x0a, 0xd7, 0x02, 0x64, 0xe3, 0xa4, 0x18, 0x54, /* ...d...T */
0x8c, 0xa2, 0xd6, 0xb1, 0xe9, 0xa5, 0x0c, 0xd2, /* ........ */
0x80, 0x18, 0x14, 0x12, 0x87, 0xf2, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
0x01, 0x01, 0x08, 0x0a, 0x4a, 0x0c, 0x9a, 0x21, /* ....J..! */
0x94, 0x8d, 0xb2, 0x23, 0x01, 0x43, 0x60, 0x00, /* ...#.C`. */
0x06, 0x00, 0x58, 0x6f, 0x12, 0x00, 0x30, 0x30, /* ..Xo..00 */
0x47, 0x00, 0x20, 0xe2, 0x82, 0x19, 0x00, 0x10, /* G. ..... */
0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x13, 0x00, 0x95, /* ........ */
0x42, 0x38, 0x14, 0x04, 0x24, 0x11, 0x57, 0x14, /* B8..$.W. */
0x58, 0x12, 0x30, 0x30, 0x11, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, /* X.00..@. */
[...]
0x39, 0x38, 0x35, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x31, 0x37, 0x00, /* 985-117. */
0x03, 0x14, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x28, 0x00, /* ......(. */
0x01, 0x19, 0x95, 0xe2, 0xcf, 0x53, 0x13, 0xa2, /* .....S.. */
0xd5                                            /* . */
};
```

My application data starts with the bytes `0x60, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00`. So I need to delete all lines and bytes up to the the application data of interest. Since I have many packets to be decoded, how do I use grep/sed to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Please don't post _images_ of text! We will need to copy your sample into a test file to be able to play with it and give you a good answer. I am not about to do so manually. Please [edit] your question and paste the actual data.

Comment: Sorry. I realized the mistake. I have now put in a link to the data. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you exported only data from your packets?

Comment: @ArturSzymczak  I wished the same. But couldn't find a way. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete the first 70 bytes:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{(?:0x[0-9a-f]{2},\s*(?:/\*.*?\*/)?\s*){70}}{}'
```

To delete up to the first `0x60, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00`:

```
perl -0777 -pe 'BEGIN{$c=qr{,\s*(?:/\*.*?\*/)?\s*}}
  s/{(?s:.*?)(?=0x60${c}0x00${c}0x06${c}0x00)/{/'
```